# FIlter function on two areas

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

Trying to filter out data from one worksheet to another.

Example of the layout:

[image: Example of the layout]

In one sheet I filter out the **B** data, which is continuous, by simply finding the start of the set with `=MATCH("B";Sheet1!A:A;0)` in a helper column, and then fill down with `=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A"&$A$5+ROW(B1))`.

I know this technically doesn't work with the example data, but Imagine that `A7` contains the text "B" and the **A** data ends at row 6.

This might not be the most elegant solution, but it works.

I'm trying to get the **A** data – but only the rows with a date – as a continuous list in the third sheet.

I found the "new" `FILTER()` function, which works well for a part of it, either with:

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A1:B7; (Sheet1!B1:B7>1;"")
```

or

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A13:B20; (Sheet1!B13:B20>1;"")
```

Is there a way to combine or get both these filtered lists after each other, or do I have to use another approach?

*I know I could do it with a macro, but I'm trying to keep this one VBA-free for once, since it's to be used in broswer, but functions aren't my strong suit.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your example FILTER statements, perhaps you could do:

```
=LET( range, Sheet1!A1:B20,
      excludeRange, Sheet1!A8:B12,
       FILTER(range,(Sheet1!B1:B20>1)*ISNA(MATCH(ROW(range),ROW(excludeRange),0)),"") )
```

Where you put in your continuous range where I put in **range** (Sheet1!A1:B20) and your excluded B range in **excludeRange** (Sheet1!A8:B12).  Sheet1!B1:B20 could also be parameterized, but I think you get the picture.

Comment: If B is not continuous, then this solution will not work. A similar approach could still be used, but the LET formula would have to be modified.

Comment: B should always be continuous, so that is fine. However I'm unfortunately using a Swedish computer at work for the moment (not allowed to change language), and can't find LET() in any of the function translation lists. But I can try this in the evening when I get home.

Comment: Realised LET is just for formatting and I don't need to use it. Seems to work at first glance!

Comment: It should be the same. https://support.microsoft.com/sv-se/office/funktionen-let-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999.  But I forgot that you have ; as argument separator, so you would have to replace the , with ; in the above formula.  Also, you can install this add-in if it is interesting. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-functions-translator-f262d0c0-991c-485b-89b6-32cc8d326889

Comment: oops - our comments just crossed.  cool.  let me know if it works.

Comment: Yeah I tried to do that, but can't install stuff. But I couldn't find how to exclude ranges in filters, so this is great. Converted it to Swedish : `=FILTER(Sheet1!A1:B20; (Sheet1!B1:B20>1) * ÄRSAKNAD(PASSA(RAD(Sheet1!A1:B20);RAD(Sheet1!A8:B12);0));"")`
And as far as I can tell, it does exactly what I want.

Comment: Super! It is useful problem. I may need to apply multiple range filters and my first instinct turned out to be wrong, so this was a learning opportunity.